# Mysql Connection time out (110).

Tags: mysql, linux

I install a archlinux system on my USB (sandisk cz80), and I find that when I connect a remote database(I use mysql-workbench),it could'nt connect.
It tells me(110: Connection timed out).
But ,when I connect my local database,it works.

And more, I use a archlinux system which installed on my SSD, it also can works!
I use the same  way , but it only works on my SSD archlinux system.

Is there anything wrong? Anyone who met the same suitation?
(PS: My mother tongue is not English, so my English is not good)

Comment: Timeout could be related to a firewall on remote db server.

Comment: yes,there is something wrong with the remote db server. I change another db server , it works.